# WPF Enable button if any text is present in textboxes (XAML only)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was asked this question in an interview.

Suppose we have 2 textboxes and a button. I want to enable/disable the button only when there is some value in both the textboxes, and I want to do that in XAML only.

Does anyone know how that is possible?

My answer was to use IMultivalue converter interface. Is this correct? Or is there any other way?

Comment: You can use a [MultiTrigger or MultiDataTrigger](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/multi-triggers-multitrigger-multidatatrigger/) for a pure XAML solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Style` with two `DataTriggers`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb1" />
<TextBox x:Name="tb2" />

<Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb1}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb2}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```